# Code igniter : Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, session

i have developed a app in codeigniter on localhost ...the app works fine .. then i uploaded the app into temporary server ... and after login into the admin panel  i am getting this error..but if i run the same app in localhost it works fine ...

error

```
  Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in  /home/u520606051/public_html/application/models/loginmodel.php on line 9
```

this my Model :

```
function validate($data)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', $data);
    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

controller

```
function verifyUser()
{
    //getting parameters from view 
    $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );      
    $this->load->model('loginModel'); 
    $query = $this->loginModel->validate($data);

    if ($query)
    {
        //if the user c validated
        //data variable is created becx we want to put username in session
        $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true  
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('sessionController/dashboard_area');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    }
```

**file name Of Modal:**

```
  loginmodel.php

 class Loginmodel extends CI_Model
```

**file name of Controller**

```
loginController.php

 class LoginController extends CI_Controller
```

Answer (score 3):

well i came up a solution by myself ..actually it was not loading the database and thus when i want to query and selecting the result i was getting this error and finally when i checked my databse.php file there is a white space in the name of database so i removed it .. thanks for all of you

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your file names, I can't guarantee, but it is almost certainly a case where you have named your model with different capitalization in the file name, class name & calling (load) name.

Your localhost is most likely Windows, which doesn't care; your server is mostly likely Linux which is case-sensitive

Go back and check that everything is the same and you'll be fine

Comment: The models itself is loading, otherwise this model can't throw the error. filenames should be working fine, i guess the $query is empty because it could not create the right object because an incorrect database connection.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, but still a little suspicious of:

    $this->load->model('loginModel'); 

Anyway, OP - your query is failing. Turn database debuggin gon in your Config file, and also try

    $this->db->last_query();

after the query line & see if it tells you anything - could be a schema or permissions issue, or something along those lines